# prompt user to build a string list

Tags: ocaml

I would like to build a string list by prompting the user for input. My end goal is to be able to parse a string list against a simple hash table using a simple routine.

```
`let list_find tbl ls = 
   List.iter (fun x -> 
     let mbr = if Hashtbl.mem tbl x then "aok" else "not found"
     in 
     Printf.printf "%s %s\n" x mbr) ls ;;`
```

Building a string list is accomplished with the cons operator ::, but somehow I am not able to get the prompt to generate a string list. A simpe list function returns anything that is put into it as a list:

```
`let build_strlist x = 
    let rec aux x = match x with
      | [] -> []
      | hd :: tl -> hd :: aux tl
    in
    aux x ;;`
```

Thus far, I have been able to set the prompt, but building the string list did not go so well. I am inclined to think I should be using Buffer or Scanning.in_channel. This is what I have thus far:

```
`#load "unix.cma" ;;
 let prompt () = Unix.isatty Unix.stdin && Unix.isatty Unix.stdout ;;

 let build_strlist () = 
   let rec loop () = 
   let eof  = ref false in 
     try
       while not !eof do
         if prompt () then print_endline "enter input ";
         let line = read_line () in 
           if line = "-1" then eof := true
           else
             let rec build x = match x with
               | [] -> []
               | hd :: tl -> hd :: build tl
             in
             Printf.printf "you've entered %s\n" (List.iter (build line));
        done
      with End_of_file -> ()
 in
 loop () ;;`
```

I am getting an error the keyword "line" has the type string, but an expression was expected of type 'a list. Should I be building the string list using Buffer.create buf and then Buffer.add_string buf prepending [ followed by quotes " another " and a semicolon? This seems to be an overkill. Maybe I should just return a string list and ignore any attempts to "peek at what we have"? Printing will be done after checking the hash table.

I would like to have a prompt routine so that I can use ocaml for scripting and user interaction. I found some ideas on-line which allowed me to write the skeleton above.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably break down the problem in several steps:

1. get the list of strings
2. process it (in your example, simply print it back)

1st step can be achieved with a recursive function as follow:

```
let build_strlist' () =
  let rec loop l =
    if prompt () then (                            
      print_string "enter input: ";
      match read_line () with
        "-1" -> l
      | s    -> loop (s::l)
   ) else l
  in loop [];;
```

See how that function loops on itself and build up the list `l` as it goes. As you mentioned in your comment, I dropped the imperative part of your code to keep the functional recursion only. You could have achieved the same by keeping instead the imperative part and leaving out the recursion, but recursion feels more natural to me, and if [written correctly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call), leads to mostly the same machine code.

Once you have the list, simply apply a `List.iter` to it with the ad hoc printing function as you did in your original function.

Comment: That's very perceptive! You have eliminated more than 50% of the code by removing imperative constructs (which read like a laundry list: do this, now do that). I have underestimated the power of 'match..with' construct and it did not occur to me to set the loop to a string list. It seems to me to be an equivalent of a "short circuit" approach in functional programming, considering "everything" as a stack instead of thinking in terms of "for each". The only thing I've changed was returning List.rev l, since insertion order is not that important for small inputs.